# error al mandar array a vista laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

tengo un error ya busque varias formas de enviarlo el array y en la misma me marca error al enviar el array ala vista.
estoy mandando un parametro al metodo putEdit($id) y este me debe hacer una consulta ala base  de datos y devolverloa a la vista edit pero me sale que no esta definida la variable pelicula en la vista.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('catalog','CatalogController@getIndex');
    Route::get('show/{id}','CatalogController@getShow');
    Route::get('create','CatalogController@getCreate');
    Route::get('edit/{id}','CatalogController@getEdit');
    Route::put('edit/{id}','CatalogController@putEdit');
    Route::post('create','CatalogController@postCreate');
});
```

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">

    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Añadir película
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body" style="padding:30px">

                {{-- TODO: Abrir el formulario e indicar el método POST --}}
                <form method="put">
                    
                    {{-- TODO: Protección contra CSRF --}}
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Modificar Título</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{$pelicula->title}}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{-- TODO: Completa el input para el año --}}
                        <label for="title">Año</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{-- TODO: Completa el input para el director --}}
                        <label for="title">Director</label>
                        <input type="text" name="director" id="director" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{-- TODO: Completa el input para el poster --}}
                        <label for="imagen">Sube la imagen:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="synopsis">Resumen</label>
                        <textarea name="synopsis" id="synopsis" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:8px 100px;margin-top:25px;">
                            Modificar película
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                {{-- TODO: Cerrar formulario --}}
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Movie;
use DB;


class CatalogController extends Controller
{   

    public function getIndex(){
        $arrayPeliculas = DB::table('movies')->get();
        return view('videoclub/index',[
            'arrayPeliculas' => $arrayPeliculas
            ]);
    }

    public function getShow($id){
        $this->id = Movie::findOrFail($id);
        return view('videoclub/show', array('id'=>$this->id) );;
    }

    public function getCreate(){
        return view('videoclub/create');
    }

    public function getEdit($id){
        $this->id = Movie::findOrFail($id);
        return view('videoclub/edit', array('id'=>$this->id) );
    }

    public function putEdit($id){
        $pelicula = DB::table('movies')->where('id', $id)->get();
        return view('videoclub/edit',[
            'pelicula' => $pelicula
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: En qué vista y qué método del controlador te aparece el error?

Comment: edit/{id} de la vista edit

Comment: veo dos métodos con Edit ...

Comment: son diferentes public function getEdit($id){
     $this->id = Movie::findOrFail($id);
        return view('videoclub/edit', array('id'=>$this->id) );
    }

    public function putEdit($id){
        $pelicula = DB::table('movies')->where('id', $id)->get();
        return view('videoclub/edit',[
            'pelicula' => $pelicula
            ]);
    }                                                                                                                        Route::get('edit/{id}','CatalogController@getEdit');
    Route::put('edit/{id}','CatalogController@putEdit');

Comment: Aún no respondes la pregunta.... es en get o en put que no funciona?

Comment: puteEdit es que marca el error estoy devolviendo el array pelicula y me dice que no esta definida en la vista

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que estás usando get(), lo cual obtiene una colección de elementos (aún si en tu caso sea solo uno el resultado de la consulta).

Deberías entonces utilizar el método `first()` para obtener solo un elemento / objeto y no una colección de estos:

```
$pelicula = DB::table('movies')->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo devolver las vistas de la siguiente manera:

```
return view('videoclub/edit')-> with(['pelicula' => $pelicula]);
```

Además controlaria si existe la pelicula:

```
public function putEdit($id){
    $pelicula = DB::table('movies')->where('id', $id)->get();
    if (!is_object($pelicula)) {
        //TODO: Avisar del error al usuario
        // Ya sea con un mensaje una vista especial, redirect a index...
        return view('videoclub/error')
    }
    return view('videoclub/edit')->with([
        'pelicula' => $pelicula
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque estas llamando a la variable `"pelicula"` en la vista y no estas mandando los datos con ese nombre.
Lo podes ver en esta linea

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="{{$pelicula->title}}">
```

Lo que yo haria es:

```
public function getEdit($id){
    $pelicula = Movie::findOrFail($id);
    return view('videoclub/edit')->with('pelicula',$pelicula);
}
```

Y en la vista entonces si podes hacer `{{$pelicula->title}}` ya que estas mandando el modelo con ese nombre.
Espero te haya sido de ayuda.
Saludos
Maru